# Eagle polygon border segmentation around pads / vias / holes

Tags: eaglecad

Why in Eagle, polygon border near pads / vias /holes are segmented? Why it is not pure circle (or following shape). Is there any setup where this can be changed?

[image]

EDIT:
Here is example where DIP via is isolated with only one connection (easier soldiering) and with thermals. Polygon around isolated via is segmented, with thermals not.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to change that? At some point the precision of the curve wont matter cause of the resolution and precision that the fab house can achieve.

Answer (score 1):

In Eagle, polygons are made of horizontal lines drawn on a grid of their line thickness. Choose a smaller line thickness for better accuracy.

Thermals create an additional circle around the via which lies over the "rough" polygon border.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because numerically stored data are stored in a coded way. For exapmle if you need to store a data representing a circle you have to give it a special code like: cir r5 x10 y10 this means that in the co-ordinate based position x = 10 & y = 10 , there is a circle of 5 units radius. But because borders around pads and vias is impossible to be a regular known shape due to there is always a track connected to it holding current. It's impossible to code it in the same way like a circle. So the simplest way to do that is to join series of small connected lines, taking nearly the same shape of pads and vias. Controlling the diatance of that line to be smaller will cause the shape to be more accurate.
It's not essential for any user to have a high resolution value at that location except that you adjust the clearnce between pads, vias, and wires.

EDIT : I have added these images to show you that only defined grounded pads has no segmentation.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]

Comment: There is 0603 resistor on 1st picture. Left pad is isolated from polygon, segmentation is present. Right pad is connected to polygon, with thermals, and polygon is perfectly follow pad shape.  If this is related to precision, segmentation will be present on both pads.

Comment: Try to look about all non segmented polygons, they are all connected to ground. This means that isolation can be made with a defined shape ( not properly a circle ) but they are defined, known, and have their unique ID code ( like cr for circles ). But the other side ( left side in your case ) is a connection made by you ( user ) which cannot be unique for every user ( even one user can make infinitely ways of connection ) which acnnot be coded as a standard. It is implemented by a somehow function like the one I have mentioned above ( connected series lines )